# DSUM with no results show as blanks

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am experiencing a bit of a problem.

My textboxes populate based on DSUMS, but if someone doesn't take a payment they are not in the table so the textbox shows blank. However I was it to at least have a zero in it.

I have tried changing the default value but still shows as a blank

Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `Nz(DSUM(stuff), 0)` replaces all `Null` values with 0

Comment: Thank you - I try this: AcashM = Nz(DSum(AcashM), 0)    And receive 'argument is not optional error'

Comment: It seems like that `DSum` statement is incomplete, don't change the `DSum`, just add the `Nz`

Comment: I see what you mean - Works a treat thank you kindly